# Custom Control Not Updating C#

Tags: c#, custom-controls, visual-c#-express-2010

I cannot for the life of me get a custom control updating itself. In the below example, "test label1" works and outputs as expected. However when I try and get it to do the same thing later on, it will not. I've tried calling Update and Invalidate, but still nothing. Am I missing something?

Swapping the points around doesn't work either, so it doesn't look like it's just off screen for example.

```
public partial class AdvancedListControl : UserControl
{
    public void createAnotherLabel()
    {
        Controls.Add(new Label { Location = new Point(14, 14), AutoSize = true, Text = "test label2 - test" }); // this won't create
        // me.Controls.Add(new Label { Location = new Point(14, 14), AutoSize = true, Text = "test label2 - test" });
        // Update();
        // Invalidate();
    }

    private AdvancedListControl me;

    public AdvancedListControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        me = this;
        Controls.Add(new Label { Location = new Point(26, 26), AutoSize = true, Text = "test label1" });
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Works for me... I just copy/pasted your code into a user control, dropped the user control onto a new form, put a button on the form, and made the button call `myAdvancedListControl.createAnotherLabel();`. I can't reproduce any issues.

Comment: Thanks for the time. I created a new clean project like yourself and yes it did work. Turns out I had two copies on my original form that I didn't realise. Thanks for the nudge as to what I should have tried in the first place. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The control method has to be called by a control driven by a end user action, like a event handler for a button, causing a page postback, this will cause the control to trigger the method and render the page with the update control state.

Answer (score 0):

Meh! Noob mistake. I did the same as Jashaszun and created a new project, and yes it did work. Turns out I had two copies of the advanced control on a form, and the one that was hiding was the one I was hitting. It's been a long day. ;-)